# Jquery slideUp and slideDown animation not working on Modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a little jquery code for showing modal. It's easy and clean. But the fact, it just working with jquery fadeIn and fadeOut animation. slideUp and slideDown animation not working. I Don't know why. Please take a look at my code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.toast-container {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 580px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
[class*="toast-pos-"] {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
}
.toast-pos-top {
  top: 0;
}
.toast-pos-right {
  right: 0;
}
.toast-pos-bottom {
  bottom: 0;
}
.toast-pos-left {
  left: 0;
}
.toast {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  background: #eeeeee;
  color: #333333;
}
.close-toast {
  float: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
/* Aditional Styles */
body {
  padding: 60px 40px;
  background: #42A5F5;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.toast-trigger {
  color: #ffffff;  
}
.toast {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.toast-trigger {
  display: inline-block;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  background: transparent;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: ease .2s;
}
.toast-trigger:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #009688;
}
</style>        
        
<a href="#" class="toast-trigger" data-toast="toast-name-1">Normal Toast</a>
<a href="#" class="toast-trigger toast-auto" data-toast="toast-name-2">Auto FadeOut Toast</a>
<div class="toast-container toast-pos-right toast-pos-bottom">
  <!-- Toast -->
  <div class="toast" id="toast-name-1">
    <a href="#" class="close-toast">&#10006;</a>
    <b>Messege 1!</b>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
  </div>
  <!-- Toast -->
  <div class="toast" id="toast-name-2">
    <a href="#" class="close-toast">&#10006;</a>
    <b>Messege 2!</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".toast-trigger").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  datatoast = $(this).attr("data-toast");
  if ( $( this ).hasClass( "toast-auto" ) && !$("#" + datatoast).is(":visible") ){ 
    $("#" + datatoast).fadeIn(300).delay(2000).fadeOut(300);
  }
  else if ( !$("#" + datatoast).is(":visible") ){
    $("#" + datatoast).fadeIn(300);
  };
});

$(".close-toast").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  closetoast = $(this).parent().attr("id");
  $("#" + closetoast).fadeOut(300);
});
</script>
```

Another fact is, if you look at this modal, there is two features. Auto fade out and click able. I want something like that "Both, click to fade and auto fade" in same modal..... That's mean combination of 2 fade features in one. How can I do it....?

Comment: Same modal means the same button?

Comment: Yes......Same Modal body close button will work as well as fade up modal.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following changes in your code and you can see the slideUp and slideDown are working.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".toast-trigger").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                datatoast = $(this).attr("data-toast");
                if ($(this).hasClass("toast-auto") && !$("#" + datatoast).is(":visible")) {
                    $("#" + datatoast).slideDown(300).delay(2000).slideUp(300);
                } else if (!$("#" + datatoast).is(":visible")) {
                    $("#" + datatoast).slideDown(300).delay(2000).slideUp(300);
                };
            });

            $(".close-toast").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                closetoast = $(this).parent().attr("id");
                $("#" + closetoast).fadeOut(300);
            });
        });
```

```css
.toast-container {
        width: 90%;
        max-width: 580px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    [class*="toast-pos-"] {
        position: absolute;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    .toast-pos-top {
        top: 0;
    }

    .toast-pos-right {
        right: 0;
    }

    .toast-pos-bottom {
        bottom: 0;
    }

    .toast-pos-left {
        left: 0;
    }

    .toast {
        display: none;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 20px 0;
        background: #eeeeee;
        color: #333333;
    }

    .close-toast {
        float: right;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #ffffff;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    /* Aditional Styles */
    body {
        padding: 60px 40px;
        background: #42A5F5;
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    .toast-trigger {
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    .toast {
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }

    .toast-trigger {
        display: inline-block;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 20px 40px;
        background: transparent;
        color: #ffffff;
        border: 1px solid #ffffff;
        text-decoration: none;
        transition: ease .2s;
    }

    .toast-trigger:hover {
        background: #ffffff;
        color: #009688;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Modal Testing</title>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="#" class="toast-trigger" data-toast="toast-name-1">Normal Toast</a>
    <a href="#" class="toast-trigger toast-auto" data-toast="toast-name-2">Auto FadeOut Toast</a>
    <div class="toast-container toast-pos-right toast-pos-bottom">
        <!-- Toast -->
        <div class="toast" id="toast-name-1">
            <a href="#" class="close-toast">&#10006;</a>
            <b>Messege 1!</b>
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
        </div>
        <!-- Toast -->
        <div class="toast" id="toast-name-2">
            <a href="#" class="close-toast">&#10006;</a>
            <b>Messege 2!</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```